# Initialize sequelize with remote credentials

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.DB_NAME || 'dev';
let config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const globalHooks = require('../config/globalHooks');
const globalSettings = require('../config/globalSettings');
config = { ...config, define: { ...globalSettings, hooks: globalHooks } };
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.username,
    config.password,

    config
  );
}
```

So I have that piece of code which gets the configuration from json file, but I'd like to get that from a remote service (let's say aws secrets) and this implies that I have to create an async function that fetches the data.

Is it possible to do that with sequelize ?

Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this isn't a sequelize problem, if your credentials are stored on a file at some web address, then you'll need to fetch those credentials first before you create you `new Sequelize(...)` instance. You can use the [https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) built-in module, although it tends to be fairly low level. For an easier API, I'd recommend [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), or [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent).

Comment: This is valid issue, sequelize has good automation with migration capabilities in cli but having async way to resolve the config or at least wait before the config file is resolved would be a good feature.